# Drop down menu on hover using CSS not working

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I was wondering if anyone could see the bug in my code I am clearly not seeing. I am trying to create a simple navigation bar with a sub menu under 'brands' that appears on hover. Not sure if I am targeting the menu wrong, or what is happening. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> History </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Brands </a> </li>
                <ul> 
                    <li> <a href="#"> Proprietary Brands </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Licenced Brands </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Distributed Brands </a> </li>
                </ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> Corp. Info </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Investors </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



.nav{
    width: 100%;
}

.nav ul{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav li li{
    font-size: 1em;
}

.nav li ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
}

.nav li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

.nav li ul li{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html just a bit wrong, it should be

```
...
    <li>
        <ul> ... </ul>
    </li>
...
```

instead

```
...
    <li> ... </li>
    <ul> ... </ul>
    <li> ... </li>
...
```

That mean you close **li** tag that should be the container of  too soon, that make your csss for **.nav li ul** and anything with that become invalid because no structure like that exist in your html

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!